# Replace specific string using sed

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

I have a *code.txt* file that contains morse code for example

> **.- .-.**

I have a function called *decode* inside a bash file called *morse* as this:

```sh
decode (){ 
   sed -i 's/ \.-/A/g' $1
   sed -i 's/ \.-./R/g' $1
   cat $1
}
```

When I type in terminal `$bash morse decode code.txt`

I receive:

> **AA.**

The output I want is :

> **AR**

How can it see separate that the string **.-** is **A** and the **.-.** is **R**?

Comment: First, run `sed -i 's/ \.-\./R/g' $1`

Comment: Run a single sed like this: `sed -i 's/ \.-\./R/g; s/ \.-/A/g' "$1"`

Comment: If all you are trying to do is output the translation to stdout, there is no need to edit the file or use `cat`.  You could just run the combined `sed` anubhava suggested without the `-i` option.  Then the output will go to stdout without the use of `cat`.  Then you can use your function like this: `decode code.txt > decoded.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `s/ \.-\./R/g` replacement first. Note the second `.` must be escaped to only match a dot.

Hence, use

```
sed 's/ \.-\./R/g;s/ \.-/A/g' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/mpTACK)

Or, another way:

```
sed -e 's/ \.-\./R/g' -e 's/ \.-/A/g' file
```

Replace the `file` with `"$1"` in your code.

**UPDATE**

Here is the translation of **encoding** / **decoding** Python function [posted by Matias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60099507/3832970) below:

```
#!/bin/bash

### Encoding:

declare -A MORSE=( [A]='.-' [B]='-...' [C]='-.-.' [D]='-..' [E]='.' [F]='..-.' [G]='--.' [H]='....' [I]='..' [J]='.---' [K]='-.-' [L]='.-..' [M]='--' [N]='-.' [O]='---' [P]='.--.' [Q]='--.-' [R]='.-.' [S]='...' [T]='-' [U]='..-' [V]='...-' [W]='.--' [X]='-..-' [Y]='-.--' [Z]='--..' [1]='.----' [2]='..---' [3]='...--' [4]='....-' [5]='.....' [6]='-....' [7]='--...' [8]='---..' [9]='----.' [0]='-----' [',']='--..--' ['.']='.-.-.-' [';']='-.-.-.' [':']='---...' ['?']='..--..' ['!']='-.-.--' ['/']='-..-.' ['-']='-....-' ['+']='.-.-.' ['(']='-.--.' [')']='-.--.-' ['_']='..--.-' ['"']='.-..-.' ["'"]='.----.' ['$']='...-..-' ['@']='.--.-.' ['&']='.-...' ['  ']=' '  )

function encode {
  res=''
  s="$1"
  for (( i=0; i<${#s}; i++ )); do
    letter="${s:$i:1}"
    if [[ "$letter" == ' ' ]]; then
      res="${res}  "
    else
      res="${res}${MORSE[${letter^^}]} ";
    fi
  done
  printf "%s" "$res"
}

echo "$(encode "THIS IS FINE")"

### Now, decoding

declare -A MORSEDEC=( ['-.--.-']=')' ['..--..']='?' ['--..--']=', ' ['-....-']='-' ['.-.-.-']='.' ['...--']='3' ['-.--.']='(' ['---..']='8' ['-..-.']='/' ['....-']='4' ['-....']='6' ['----.']='9' ['.----']='1' ['..---']='2' ['.....']='5' ['--...']='7' ['-----']='0' ['-...']='B' ['-..-']='X' ['-.-.']='C' ['--..']='Z' ['--.-']='Q' ['.-..']='L' ['-.--']='Y' ['..-.']='F' ['.--.']='P' ['.---']='J' ['...-']='V' ['....']='H' ['-..']='D' ['---']='O' ['..-']='U' ['...']='S' ['.--']='W' ['-.-']='K' ['.-.']='R' ['--.']='G' ['-.']='N' ['..']='I' ['--']='M' ['.-']='A' ['  ']=' ' ['.']='E' ['-']='T' )

function decode {
  res=''
  tmp="$(sed 's/ \{2,\}/ | /g' <<< "$1")";
  for word in $tmp; do
    if [[ "$word" == '|' ]]; then
      res="${res}${MORSEDEC['  ']}";
    else
      res="${res}${MORSEDEC[$word]}";
    fi
  done
  printf "%s" "$res"
}
echo "$(decode "- .... .. ...   .. ...   ..-. .. -. .")"
```

See [Bash demo online](https://ideone.com/quHrLr).

Comment: Yes but that was an example..What can I do in the case of having all letters of alphabet..For example also "L" is **.-..** this means that I must do the same for L

Comment: @P.Bes That is the same idea: the longer patterns should be handled before the shorter.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to encode and decode Morse messages with *any* tool then something like this will do :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import re

alphabet = { 'A':'.-', 'B':'-...', 'C':'-.-.', 'D':'-..', 'E':'.', 'F':'..-.', 'G':'--.', 'H':'....', 'I':'..', 'J':'.---', 'K':'-.-', 'L':'.-..', 'M':'--', 'N':'-.', 'O':'---', 'P':'.--.', 'Q':'--.-', 'R':'.-.', 'S':'...', 'T':'-', 'U':'..-', 'V':'...-', 'W':'.--', 'X':'-..-', 'Y':'-.--', 'Z':'--..', '1':'.----', '2':'..---', '3':'...--', '4':'....-', '5':'.....', '6':'-....', '7':'--...', '8':'---..', '9':'----.', '0':'-----', ', ':'--..--', '.':'.-.-.-', '?':'..--..', '/':'-..-.', '-':'-....-', '(':'-.--.', ')':'-.--.-',' ':'  '} 

def encode(message): 
    return "".join([ ( alphabet[letter.upper()] + ' ' ) if letter != ' ' else '  ' for letter in message])

def decode(message):
    return "".join([ list(alphabet.keys())[list(alphabet.values()).index(item if item != '|' else '  ')] for item in re.sub(r' {2,}', ' | ',message).split(' ')])

print(encode('THIS IS FINE'))
print(decode('- .... .. ...   .. ...   ..-. .. -. .'))
```

Hope it helps too.

Comment: That a good effort. I am searching for something like that but in a bash file with unix not in python..I would appreciate if you can help me there.

Comment: @P.Bes Well you are in the right track if thats your goal. *sed* looks like a good start.  Let me see how much of that Python script I can translate to Bash. Can you use *awk* at least? or you need pure bash?

Comment: pure bash I think

Answer (score 1):

Wow interesting idea! Based on @MatiasBarrios alphabet i made this.

```
#!/bin/bash

string=$1

declare -A morse=(
    [A]='.-'    [B]='-...'  [C]='-.-.'  [D]='-..'   [E]='.'
    [F]='..-.'  [G]='--.'   [H]='....'  [I]='..'    [J]='.---'
    [K]='-.-'   [L]='.-..'  [M]='--'    [N]='-.'    [O]='---'
    [P]='.--.'  [Q]='--.-'  [R]='.-.'   [S]='...'   [T]='-'
    [U]='..-'   [V]='...-'  [W]='.--'   [X]='-..-'  [Y]='-.--'
    [Z]='--..'

    [1]='.----'  [2]='..---'  [3]='...--'  [4]='....-'  [5]='.....'
    [6]='-....'  [7]='--...'  [8]='---..'  [9]='----.'  [0]='-----'
    [(]='-.--.'  [)]='-.--.-' [/]='-..-.'  [-]='-....-' [+]='.-.-.'
    [.]='.-.-.-' [,]='--..--' [?]='..--..' [!]='-.-.--' [ ]='  '
)

morse () {
    while [[ "$string" ]]; do
        symbol="${string::1}"
        printf -- "${morse["${symbol^}"]} "
        string="${string:1}"
    done
}

demorse () {
    declare -A demorse
    for item in "${!morse[@]}"; { demorse["${morse["$item"]}"]="$item"; }
    while [[ $@ ]]; do
        printf -- "${demorse["$1"],}"
        shift
    done
}

case $string in
    demorse) shift; demorse "$@";;
    *      )          morse     ;;
esac
```

Usage

```
$ ./morse 'hello world!'
.... . .-.. .-.. ---    .-- --- .-. .-.. -.. -.-.--
```

Demorse also worsk but, spaces have to be printed like this `'  '`

```
$ ./morse demorse .... . .-.. .-.. --- '  ' .-- --- .-. .-.. -.. -.-.--
hello world!
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer in RE engines that support look-ahead and look-behind would be to treat the spaces as look-ahead and look-behind triggers, but sed does not support this.

Another option that avoids needing to order the letters is to inject extra symbols to help you mark each letter. Say we inject = round each space, then we can replace delimited sequences in any order, and finally get rid of the delimiters:

```
echo  .- .-.|sed -e 's/^\(.*\)$/=\1=/;s/ /= =/g' -e 's/=\.-\.=/=R=/g;s/=\.-=/=A=/g' -e 's/= =//g;s/^=//;s/=$//'
```

If you have rules that need to preserve multiple spaces, then that can be accommodated.